# Cannot use lua libraries in C++

Tags: c++, lua

Ok, so I've tried compiling a simple C++ lua program on linux/Ubuntu; 
Firt, I installed the lua libs : I downloaded the lua sources and compiled it myself like this :

```
`sudo make linux install` /// in the `lua src` directory
```

It worked : when I called lua in the command lin, it showed me the version, lua 5.3.1; Then, I wrote a simple C++ program using this lua lib :

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern "C" {
    #include "lua.h"
    #include "lualib.h"
    #include "lauxlib.h"
}

/* the Lua interpreter */
lua_State* L;

static int average(lua_State *L)
{
    /* get number of arguments */
    int n = lua_gettop(L);
    double sum = 0;
    int i;

    /* loop through each argument */
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        /* total the arguments */
        sum += lua_tonumber(L, i);
    }

    /* push the average */
    lua_pushnumber(L, sum / n);

    /* push the sum */
    lua_pushnumber(L, sum);

    /* return the number of results */
    return 2;
}

int main ( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    /* initialize Lua */
    L = luaL_newstate();

    /* load Lua base libraries */
    luaL_openlibs(L);

    /* register our function */
    lua_register(L, "average", average);

    /* run the script */
    luaL_dofile(L, "avg.lua");

    /* cleanup Lua */
    lua_close(L);

    /* pause */
    printf( "Press enter to exit..." );
    getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

But when I compile it like this : 
 `g++ test.cpp -o output -llua`

I get the following error :

```
loadlib.c:(.text+0x502): undefined reference to `dlsym'
loadlib.c:(.text+0x549): undefined reference to `dlerror'
loadlib.c:(.text+0x576): undefined reference to `dlopen'
loadlib.c:(.text+0x5ed): undefined reference to `dlerror'
//usr/local/lib/liblua.a(loadlib.o): In function `gctm':
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Add `-ldl` to the compiler command line. The missing functions are needed for loading C extension modules from shared libraries. For future reference: typing `man dlsym` (or any other referenced function) in the terminal will show you what this function is about and also mentions that you have to link with `-ldl`.

Comment: It worked!!!!!!! Thanks, I've been looking all over the internet for nearly 3 hours! Finally I can use lua as a scripting language; can you suggest me any book or tutorial ?

Comment: For learning materials, see http://www.lua.org/start.html#learning.

Comment: There is no need for that `lua_State* L`  to be a global declaration. Note that it is *not* seen in `average` because it is shadowed by the argument.

Comment: Yes, I know ! Only a quick test program taken from the internet; I 've done the things in the way they should of using R.A.I.I. wrappers !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the [readme](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/readme.html), `make linux` in the Lua `src` directory (or in the top-level directory) produces three files: `lua` (the interpreter), `luac` (the compiler), and `liblua.a` (the library).

`lua` (the interpreter) is an ordinary Lua client, just like yours. The build line shown by `make linux` for it is:

```
gcc -std=gnu99 -o lua lua.o liblua.a -lm -Wl,-E -ldl -lreadline
```

Note the presence `-ldl`. Note also `-Wl,-E`, which allows Lua API symbols to be resolved when `lua` (the interpreter) loads dynamic C libraries. If you plan to load dynamic C libraries with your program, then rebuild it with `-Wl,-E`.